# Content Security Policy Meta Tag Being Ignored

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-security-policy

I would like to enable CSP on my site via the use of the meta tag in html. Here is my current tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' filesystem; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/*; img-src 'self' filesystem https://*; child-src 'self' https://player.twitch.tv/* https://www.twitch.tv/*; script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com/* https://player.twitch.tv/* filesystem;">
```

All of the above works, apart from any mention to any of the external URLS. None of the bootstrap, jQuery, or twitch requests are being allowed through and all are being blocked, for example:

"Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' *.bootstrapcdn.com". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

Any ideas why all of the filesystem stuff is being acknowledged, yet any rules referring to external http requests aren't being allowed through?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that a default header is added as the policy is different than the one you have included in the question. This would also be the reason why other external requests are blocked. You should include any CSPs that are actually served with your page in your question, both CSP in headers and meta.

Minor details of browser implementations vary a lot, this could be the reason why filesystem works for you. You should list which browsers you have tested.

Comment: I have only tested chrome, and I am using github pages with cloudflare CDN. I am doing this through meta tag as github pages doesn't allow you to add custom headers or anything